# Can I use extension to pass login and password to OpenID provider?

Tags: authentication, openid, offline

There will be login page via OpenID controlled by an extension. Can I ask for URL and pass in the extension and then pass it OP by use of extension? If no what kind of data can be transferred to OP from RP by an extension? If yes, how scalable it is, do I have to write separate code of each OP, or will the standard help me?
Also in unlikely case of XY problem - I need some sort of data that will allow me to authenticate OpenID user offline (after at least one successful online login). So if I was the one to provide login and password text fields I would be able to use user's password hash it and use for offline auth. And yes I need to use OpenID rather that other system, because this is the requirement. Sorry, It's kind of ugly problem.

Comment: What programming language? Are you using any library for OpenID? What are you referring to when you say "an extension," i.e. an extension in C# might refer to an extension method?

Comment: That's an excellent question. I am still in design phase. Haven't entirely decided on language yet. This is offline/online app running in sort of browser. An extension is browser extension. It will provide a login page an sort of control the whole process (again it has to be extension - req.)

Comment: "sort of browser" is a smelly term. OpenID is only compatible with web applications, because the user is required to type their password in the OpenID provider's page. As far as I know, the OpenID standard does not provide a way to transmit the user's password, **nor should it!**

Comment: I don't want OpenID to pass password. I won't to pass password to OpenID.

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment: the OpenID standard does not provide a way to transmit the user's password neither from nor **TO** an OpenID provider. It's just not in the standard, so you can't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're supposed to pass a user id/password to the OpenID provider (or at least not password). The idea behind OpenID is that the provider takes care of the login, thus the **web** application utilizing OpenID will have no knowledge of the login credentials. OpenID provides you with some [authorization information](http://openid.net/specs/openid-simple-registration-extension-1_1-01.html#response_format), such as the nickname, fullname, email, etc. This information, coupled with the OpenID of the user itself, should be enough provide you with unique authentication for that user without the need to have a password.

Your application needs to allow the user to go to the OpenID provider's page, enter their credentials there, and once authenticated you will get a response from OpenID indicating whether the authentication is successful and subsequently providing you with the user's information.

### Update

Like I mentioned in my comments: the OpenID standard does not define a way in which you can send a password to an OpenID provider. So you can't use the OpenID standard in the manner you're envisioning it.

### Update 2.0

Let's take [myOpenID](https://www.myopenid.com/) for example: in order to use myOpenID as an OpenID provider you have to register your domain with OpenID. Alternately, you can [enable OpenID for your website by contacting Janrian](https://www.myopenid.com/website_enablement) (the owners of myOpenID), but I'm going to say you're still going to have to register a website with them. In either case, you must have a landing page on your domain, or on your website, which accepts an authentication response from the OpenID provider (in this case myOpenID). So let's look at what's required:

1. You must spoof a web browser when you're making the web request to the myOpenID provider.
2. In that web request, you have fill in the form which takes in the client's password (again, you have to spoof the client doing that).
3. You have to have a service of some sort running on a website registered with an OpenID provider (such as myOpenID).
4. You will have to send a message (HTTP) to the service that you're expecting an authentication response for a specific user (and provide it with a way to call you back when the user is authenticated).
5. That service will take any incoming authentication response from the OpenID provider.
6. The service will match that authentication with the user ID that you told it to expect in step 4.
7. The service will send your application the authentication response (callback).
8. You must accept the authentication response from that service.

The hardest part will probably be step 1 and 2, but there should be plenty of tutorials online that can show you how to do this (sorry I didn't have time to look up specific ones).

In any case, that's how I would imagine you may be able to do this, but it's far from trivial and I've never seen it done before.

Part of the reason why OpenID is so popular is exactly because people don't have to share their credentials with the service provider (i.e. your app), they only share it with the OpenID provider. The other thing you should think about is whether or not users will agree to use the OpenID in the manner that you want them to use it. **In other words, one of the main reasons why people use OpenID providers is so that they avoid doing exactly what you're asking them to do: give you their password!**

### Update 3.0

You can register your domain with myOpenID by going to the new domain registration page: https://www.myopenid.com/new_domain

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I do realize how OpenID works and how should it work. But unfortunately my app is very very special app that needs different use case. I understand that this is not the way you should use OpenID. Given above I still want to do it. I want to take advantage of OpenID popularity and extensibility rather than decentralised login. So I would really appreciate answer to question "Can I do it?" rather that "Should I do it?".

Comment: The answer to both is no: you can't do it and you shouldn't do it :). OpenID does not define a way for you to transmit the user's password to a provider.

Comment: And again, I know that specs does not provide a way to do this. I read the spec. Still "Can it be done?" using extension, for example automatically filling in form fields in OP page?

Comment: @nivwusquorum you can make a web request that sends the user information (password, etc.) to the OpenID provider, but then you have no way to get the authentication confirmation. If you take myOpenID (an OpenID provider) for example: you have to register your website with myOpenID in order to get authentication back to the application running on that website's server. I don't know about the other OpenID providers, but I imagine they work the same way, so the only way you're going to get this to work is if you have a server that you can register with the provider.

Comment: @nivwusquorum updated again with a possible "hack," but it's far from pretty or trivial.

Comment: And this is what I am talking about. Thanks very much for your response! Also one more thing, can you write a few more words about registering the user with the provider? I didn't see it in the spec. Do you have to register with each OP separately to use OpenID in your app?

Comment: Terribly sorry for confusing you I mean registering website/app with the provider of course. User is separate problem that I will deal with in the flow.

Comment: Got it... still Update 3.0, you can register your domain here: https://www.myopenid.com/new_domain

Comment: Do i have to do it separately for each provider?

Comment: @nuivwusquorum As far as I know, yes, you have to register separately with each provider.